# Find Goodreads books in Library catalog

Tags: web-apps, books

I have a huge list of books I want to read in Goodreads. My library has a lot of books I can check out on Overdrive (and a few other sources like OneClickDigital). Is there a web app that can quickly find the intersection of the books that I want to read and the books that are available for me to read? It seems like this should exist because both [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/api) and [Overdrive](https://developer.overdrive.com/apis) have APIs.

A web application to find my Goodreads to-read list on World Cat would be helpful, too, because I could filter WorldCat down to the libraries that I have access to.

It sounds like I may be able to export my Goodreads list to some local book-managing software, and then use a "Library Finder" plugin from there, but I would prefer a web app. Presumably a web app would have an easier time syncing the to-read list from Goodreads with the "Available" list from my library.

Answer (score 2):

## [Available Goodreads](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/available-goodreads/gclnfffacbjpclfenjgefpfnafmjghhk) extension for Chrome

Not a web app, but this is probably better. Only works for Overdrive. It adds "Available on Overdrive" to Goodreads book description pages, bookshelves, and Listopia book lists. Also indicates if it's an audio book, how many copies are on hold, etc. This is going to help me <s>save</s> waste time more productively.

[image: Owl Moon description page with Available Goodreads extension, showing one audiobook available and one ebook available]

[image: on overdrive column added to to-read shelf]

[image: Entries added to Listopia lists]

If there is more than one search result, hover over the link to check the full title and description:

[image: Hover link to filter through multiple search results]